# MYSQL select statement through multiple associative entities

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am trying to retrieve data through multiple associative entities, namely **company_area** (in pink) and **jobs_employees** (in blue). I want to retrieve all the **jobs** (in green) that **employees** (in grey) did from a specific **company** and **area**. How would I do this with the database structure I have?

***What I've tried:***

```
select Jobs.idJobs,jobs.Title, jobs.JobDescription, jobs.Deadline, 
jobs.JobStarted, jobs.jobEnded, jobs.Completed, jobs.Remarks, Priority

from company_area

inner join employees 
on employees.idEmployees = company_area.FK_Employee
inner join jobs_employees
on jobs_employees.FK_Employees = employees.idEmployees
inner join JobPriority 
on jobs_employees.FK_Priority = JobPriority.idJobPriority
inner join jobs
on jobs_employees.FK_Employees = jobs.idJobs 

where company_area.FK_Company = '2' and company_area.FK_Area = '1'
```

***Notes:***
I know I can create an associative entity between company, area, and jobs but is it possible and efficient to do it without the extra entity?

[Code to create DB >>](http://www.hydrocell.co/DB_structure.html)
 [image: ERD diagram]

Comment: What is the problem with the query you posted? It seems fine, Do you got any errors? not the desired result? Please explain.

Comment: Not the desired result. I want the jobs ONLY from an employee that workes in a specific area and company. Maybe you can try add more jobs, employees, areas and companies and take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few advices:

1. There is no magic: if you access a table to obtain column value or to join other, you definitely need the table.
2. Possible problem in your query: you can get one job several times if job is performed by a few users.
3. Better use table prefix for all columns. Column name with prefix FK is a bit misleading - it is standard prefix for naming foreign keys.